# Powershell forum with button calling script

Tags: powershell, invoke

I have a powershell forum for level 1.
Now it has been asked to add a button that calls an script for solving automatic outlook issues.

The script works when i call it direct on the computer itself (via .\outlook.ps1)

When i add it to the button it does not work.

The button itself works and is visible.

example code:

```
$button_Outlookrest_Click={
    Get-ComputerTXTBOX
    Add-logs -text "$ComputerName - Create new Outlook profile"
    function button{
    Copy-Item -Path "D:\path\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1" -Destination "\\$ComputerName\C$\local" -Recurse
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock  {C:\local\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1}
    }
    }
```

I have tested the code individual, and the following is working:

```
Copy-Item -Path "D:\path\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1" -Destination "\\replaced-with-targetcomputer\C$\local" -Recurse
```

When i whant to call the script, i use the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock  {C:\local\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1}
```

However, above text provides me below error:

PS C:\Users\admin> Invoke-Command -ComputerName targetcomputer -ScriptBlock  {C:\local\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1}

[targetcomputer] Connecting to remote server targetcomputer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By
default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (clienttarget:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

i want to avoid them using powershell, as its not the idea of this button.

in the script itself, it does not copy the file to the target computer, it does not run the script using the invoke command.
Is this blocked by company firewall?
Do i have something wrong in my code?
An example button that works without any problem is:

```
    $button_DriverQuery_Click={
    $button_DriverQuery.Enabled = $False
    Get-ComputerTxtBox
    $DriverQuery_command="cmd.exe"
    $DriverQuery_arguments = "/k driverquery /s $ComputerName"
    Start-Process $DriverQuery_command $DriverQuery_arguments
    $button_DriverQuery.Enabled = $true
}
```

Only this aditional button does not work. And i cannot figure it out at the moment.
What am i doing wrong here?

thank you.

Comment: Are all the client machines configured for [WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management) / [PSRemoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1). There are a few guides on configuring WinRM by GPO if you search `GPO PowerShell WinRM` - take your pick)). What PowerShell version are all the machines running? Do the firewalls allow ports 5985/5986 between the machines in question? All useful things to check.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I will check if it is turned on or not. Normaly when we do a remote to machines via text based, we use psexec, then invoke powershell (psexec \\computername -s powershell (or cmd). I will do a gp check and search for provided paramenter. if this does not work, what other options do i have to use the copied script on the computer? are there alternatives?

Comment: There isn't really any reason why it shouldn't work if the clients have a compatible version of PowerShell installed, the network access is in place and PowerShell is configured to allow WinRM. I would personally avoid having PSExec about.

Comment: Yes, i agree about PSExec, however, this is used per default in the network i am working with unfortantly.. I had no time yet to check the WInRM. Tomorrow is other day to verify this. The copy-item command works without any problem, and this is also used with $computer, so its strange setup. I will also test other machines, to see if its only related to some machines. ps the test is done on my fixed vdi machine.I can find a test machine to use this on. thank you anyhow. And all clients incluiding vdi's are windows 10 1809 based machines with latest updates.

Comment: If this is some helpdesk function, then it would be pertinent to check the privileges under which your app and PowerShell will be running on top of ensuring WinRM can be used in all the machines it needs to be.

Comment: yes, i agree, the strange thing is, that it is only the invoke command that seems to be blocking. if this is the case, then i cannot use it this way. Is there an alternative to use above way, without using the invoke command? ofcourse, i can force WinRM to activate, but this is considered inside this company a security risk (dont ask why). So i think i need to find some kind of workarround. This monday i have a sit rep regading this script with some lvl3 departmens. mabey they can provide some usefull input.

Comment: ok, got a bit futher.i have removed the following code: function button. It copys the file to the desired location, but invoke command is disabled on the network due to security reasons. Dont ask why. gpo thing. So, i am forced to use psexec, even if i do not want. next command i found somewhere in a forum psexec \\$ComputerName -s cmd /c "echo . | powershell c:\local\Repair_outlook_Profile.ps1" and is working. i do see psexec running on target machine. but script itself  hangs somewhere. so i need to figure that out. this is solved. thank you for your input.